# How to protect solr on document level except admin level

Tags: solr, solrcloud

How to protect solr on document level. I have protected solr on admin level but still i can get response through curl request

http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=xml&indent=true

Answer (score 0):

You can add roles to access only specific collections or even search / update handlers. More info here
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Rule-Based+Authorization+Plugin

Here are some more links about Document Level Security if the above is not what you are looking for:

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/document-level-security-filter-solution-for-Solr-td4126992.html

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Document_Level_Security